# Require a property to be overridden when inheriting from a non-abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance

Is there a way to require a property to be overridden in a derived class when base class is not abstract? For example:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected abstract string Test {get;}
}

internal class FirstClass : BaseClass
{
    protected override string Test => "First Class";
    // Methods common to FirstClass and SecondClass
}

internal class SecondClass : FirstClass
{
    protected override string Test => "Second Class"
}
```

Is there a way to force property `test` in `FirstClass` to be overridden if any class inherits from `FirstClass`?

There is practical need for this (maybe not a big one) is that while logging information, we want to log source of error (class name etc.), therefore we want to  force all leaf derived class to override certain properties.

Comment: Because its an existing code base and FirstClass already has many methods reusable by SecondClass. Also its not good practice to move these common methods to base because other class inherits from base don't need these methods...

Comment: If what you want is to log the class name then why not simply have your logging code call `this.GetType().Name` ?

Comment: The story is long, but short story is because legacy code is designed in a way we could not do that :(.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to require a property to be overridden in a derived class when base class is not abstract?

(The original question asks about fields. Fields may not be overridden at all; you meant "property", not "field".)

No.

Whether a derived class chooses to override or not is an implementation detail that is up to the author of that derived class, who knows more about the business domain of that class than the author of the base class knows.

The only way to make a member that must be overridden is to make it abstract.

It *is* legal to override with an abstract. This would be legal, for instance:

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual string Test => "Base";
}
abstract class FirstClass : BaseClass
{
    // override abstract is slightly unusual but legal
    protected override abstract string Test { get; }
    // Concrete derived classes must override
}
class SecondClass : FirstClass
{
    protected override string Test => "Second Class"
}
```